# Пересоздание списка ArrayList для навигации в глубину по ReyclerView

Tags: android, база-данных, recyclerview, arraylist, dao

Пытаюсь построить навигацию на основе ArrayList. Логика достаточно простая - если `parent_id` равен `0`, то эти элементы высвечиваются сразу при переходе на фрагмент с RecyclerView. За это отвечает вот этот запрос из `Dao`.

```
@Query("SELECT * from word_table WHERE parent_id = 0")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();
```

После нажатия на элемент из начального списка `ArrayList` должен полностью очиститься и заполниться теми элементами, чей `parent_id` , для примера, равен `1`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE parent_id = :id")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords(final int id);
```

Это должно продолжать до тех пор, пока у всех элементов из вновь созданного списка не выполнится условие `has_products = true`.
Как можно реализовать такую навигацию?.

Вот сама база дынных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот исходники кода.
База данных

```
@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 6, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract WordDao wordDao();

// marking the instance as volatile to ensure atomic access to the variable
private static volatile WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}


private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        // If you want to keep the data through app restarts,
        // comment out the following line.
        new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();
    }
};


private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final WordDao mDao;

    PopulateDbAsync(WordRoomDatabase db) {
        mDao = db.wordDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {

        mDao.deleteAll();

        Word word = new Word(
                1,
                0,
                "Category 1",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                2,
                0,
                "Category 2",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                3,
                0,
                "Category 3",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                4,
                0,
                "Category 4",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                5,
                1,
                "Subcategory 1.1",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                6,
                1,
                "Subcategory 1.2",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                7,
                1,
                "Subcategory 1.3",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                8,
                2,
                "Subcategory 2.1",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                9,
                2,
                "Subcategory 2.2",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word(
                10,
                3,
                "Subcategory 3.1",
                "http://185.83.242.116/media/photo_2018-08-20_12-55-11.jpg",false);
        mDao.insert(word);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {

@Query("SELECT * from word_table WHERE parent_id = 0")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();

@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE parent_id = :id")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords(final int id);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void insert(Word word);

@Query("SELECT has_products FROM WORD_TABLE WHERE id = :id")
boolean hasProducts(final int id);

@Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
void deleteAll();
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private int parentId;
private ArrayList<MenuPosition> ourMenuItems;

private WordViewModel mWordViewModel;

public MainActivity() {
    this.ourMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    final WordListAdapter adapter = new WordListAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
    mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);

    mWordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Word> words) {
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            adapter.setWords(words);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Адаптер `RecyclerView`

```
public class WordListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder> {

class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView wordItemView;
    private final ImageView imageView;

    private WordViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        wordItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Word> mWords; // Cached copy of words

WordListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
    return new WordViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mWords != null) {
        Word current = mWords.get(position);
        holder.wordItemView.setText(current.getWord());
        Picasso.get().load(current.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
    } else {
        // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
        holder.wordItemView.setText("No Word");
    }
}

void setWords(List<Word> words) {
    mWords = words;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
// mWords has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mWords != null)
        return mWords.size();
    else return 0;
}
}
```